# Is there a Cascade delete option for localdb (mdf) in VS 2013

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

In my SQL Server 2014 database I can set the option for cascade delete on some of my keys/relationships, however I have since changed to using a localdb `.mdf` file in my `app_data` folder in MVC. Inside this `localdb` I have replicated what I had in my SQL Server database.

I needed this option for working on different computers and transporting it around. However when recreating the database in the localdb I forgot to add the option of cascade delete.

I have been rummaging around in the SQL Server Explorer Object window and I have right clicked on every table and key associated with the tables but I cannot find the option in Visual Studio for `cascade delete`:

[image]

Comment: it should be on the foreig key, but you can Always drop and add the foreign key with an alter table script

Comment: I think entity framework has an option for cascade delete, I remember turning it off for one of my applications before. Perhaps you need to do it in there?

Comment: Hi @AbdulAhmad the option exists in EF however it cant be done from EF's side. It has to be done at the database end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select `View Designer` (or `Open Table Definition`) on the table at the left side. Then you can add a foreign key on the right side of the table definition. You should also see the T-SQL definition of the table. There you can add the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` or `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause as needed.

For example:

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_Posts_PostTags] 
   FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES [PostTags]([PostId])
      ON UPDATE CASCADE
      ON DELETE CASCADE
```